# Undefined variables in point in polygon function

Tags: php, variables, polygon

I created a function to see if a lat/lon are inside a polygon. I'm getting these notice: undefined variable: xx.xx but its an array of lat/lons being passed and its the value that is undefined not the array. I'm confused help please. The line is the second / the last if statement

```
     public function checkCoordinates($lat, $lon, $polylat, $polylon) {
      $j = count($polylat)-1;//number of sides and -1 because its an array
      $result = true;
      for($i=0;$i<count($polylat);$i++){
           if($polylat[$i]<$lat && $polylat[$j]>=$lat
           || $polylat[$j]<$lat && $polylat[$i]>=$lat){ //if the latitude at the beggining is bigger than and at the end is smaller than or vise versa
                if($polylon[$i]+($lat-$polylat[$i])/($$polylat[$j]-$polylat[$i])*($polylon[$j]-$polylon[$i])<$lon){ //
                     $result = false;
                }
           }
      $j=$i;
      }
      return $result;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't notice the extra $, that explains it